# Cannot center a div inside a div? (html,css)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center the items in a navbar (a div inside a div) but it either floats to the right or to the left, but never really in a center position.

(I'm using "navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" for the style of the navbar).

*topnav2* is a "logo" that is perfectly placed to the left, but I want the items inside *topnav* to be placed in th *center* right next to the logo in *topnav2*.

```css
.topnav a {
    display: inline-block;
  color: #777777;

  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size:22px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;


}

.topnav2 a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #777777;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size:22px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="topnav2">
        <a class="navtitle" href="index.html">Projekt</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
        <a href="#">Platzhalter 1</a>
        <a href="#">Platzhalter 2</a>
        <a href="#">Platzhalter 3</a>   
    </div>
</div>
```

like mentioned above, *topnav2* is placed perfectly how I want it, but I somehow couldn't figure out how to center topnav next to *topnav2*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need just another container to do that?

```css
.topnav a {
    display: inline-block;
  color: #777777;

  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size:22px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;


}

.topnav2 a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #777777;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size:22px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="topnav2">
    <a class="navtitle" href="index.html">Projekt</a> 
</div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
     <a href="#">Platzhalter 1</a>
     <a href="#">Platzhalter 2</a>
     <a href="#">Platzhalter 3</a>   
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Or you can use that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div

Comment: this one worked perfectly, but when I resize my window, the burger dropdown icon suddenly jumps under the active "home" menu. any fix to that? oh nevermind I found the fix

Answer (score 0):

Just give `text-align:center` CSS to element `.topnav`.

Try this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z7px5byc/) or see below code may be it can help you-

```css
.topnav{
  text-align: center;
}

.topnav a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #777777;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.topnav2 a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #777777;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="topnav2">
    <a class="navtitle" href="index.html">Projekt</a>
  </div>
  <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Platzhalter 1</a>
    <a href="#">Platzhalter 2</a>
    <a href="#">Platzhalter 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to center your navigation and put your links in list items.

```css
.main-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.main-nav a {
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #60B99A;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="main-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">nav 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">nav 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">nav 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">nav 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine in my page `.navbar{
    text-align: center;
}`